# Is the Church-Kleene Ordinal describable with Kleene's $O$?

Tags: logic, computability, ordinals, proof-theory, foundations

Kleene's $O$ is an ordinal notation system that uses certain natural numbers to represent transfinite ordinals.  It is a recursive notation system (although it's not decidable whether a number represents an ordinal whether two numbers represent the same ordinal), so naturally we can only represent recursive ordinals, i.e. order types of recursive well-orderings.  The smallest ordinal we cannot represent in Kleene's $O$ is the Church-Kleene ordinal $\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}}$, the smallest non-recursive ordinal, so it is the order type of the recursive ordinals, i.e. the order type of the ordinals that can be represented in Kleene's $O$.  (This leads to the result that the set of natural numbers in Kleene's $O$ is not recursive, or even recursively enumerable.)  Since $\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}}$ is non-recursive, it follows that you can't have a recursive well-ordering in Kleene's $O$ that has order-type $\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}}$.

Yet [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_countable_ordinal#A_pseudo-well-ordering) mentions a remarkable fact:

"Within the scheme of notations of Kleene some represent ordinals and some do not. One can define a recursive total ordering that is a subset of the Kleene notations and has an initial segment which is well-ordered with order-type $\omega_1^{\mathrm{CK}}$. Every recursively enumerable (or even hyperarithmetic) nonempty subset of this total ordering has a least element. So it resembles a well-ordering in some respects. For example, one can define the arithmetic operations on it. Yet it is not possible to effectively determine exactly where the initial well-ordered part ends and the part lacking a least element begins."

First of all, does anyone know the details of how this recursive subset is defined?  I'm more interested in the last part: "it is not possible to effectively determine exactly where the initial well-ordered part ends and the part lacking a least element begins."  I assume that if you partitioned a recursive totally ordered set $X$ into two parts $A$ and $B$, such that every element of $A$ is less than every element of $B$, then both $A$ and $B$ are recursive totally ordered sets.  Am I wrong about that?  If I'm right, then is the article saying that a partition of the recursive subset into the well-ordered part and the non-well-ordered part CAN be done recursively, but we can't tell recursively which partition is the one we want?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit too long to fully describe here. I can give you references.

Sacks's *Higer Recursion Theory* is a good source for learning about the ordinal notations and Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$.

I believe wikipedia above is describing the $\Pi_1^1$ set of unique notations in Kleene $\mathcal{O}$. This is constructed using the Harrison Ordering, which is a recursive linear ordering which is not a well-ordering but has no hyperarithmetic decreasing sequence. It also has an initial sequence of order type $\omega_1^\text{CK}$. In fact the order type of the Harrison Ordering is $\omega_1^{CK}(1 + \eta) + \gamma$ where $\eta$ is the order type of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\gamma$ is some computable ordinal.

The relevant section to learn about the set of unique notations and the Harrison Ordering is page 55-58 in Sacks's Book. I believe the book is available online.

Comment: Indeed it is: [Projet Euclid link](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422631).

Comment: @William Thanks for this.  Does Sacks discuss my question about whether the well-ordered initial segment of the Harrison Ordering is a recursive set?  Also, is anything known about what specific ordinal this mysterious $\gamma$ is?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The Harrison Linear ordering is recursive in the sense that it is isomorphic to a computable linear ordering of $\omega$. This does not mean that the Harrison Linear Ordering sitting inside of $\mathcal{O}$ is a computable subset of $\mathcal{O}$. Also the Harrison Ordering is constructed by using a arbitrary recursive linear ordering with no hyperarithmetic descreasing sequence. So the $\gamma$ will probably depend on which one you choose.

Comment: @William So is the Harrison Ordering NOT a computable subset of $O$?

Comment: Wikipedia and Sacks does not say that the Harrison Ordering is computable as it sits inside of $\mathcal{O}$. However, the well-ordering ititial segment is definitely not recursive. If it was, then the initial is isomorphic to an computable ordinal. But we know the initial segment is $\omega_1^{CK}$ which is not computable. Although I suspect the Harrison Order is not recursive inside $\mathcal{O}$, even if it was, the initial segment is a limit ordinal so I do not see any way this would imply the initial segment is computable.

Comment: @William If $X$ is a totally ordered recursive set and you partition $X$ into two parts $A$ and $B$ such that every element of $A$ is less than every element of $B$, then don't $A$ and $B$ have to be recursive?

Comment: If the $<$ relation is recursive, then for any fixed $z$, $\{x : x < z\}$ is recursive. But there is no element in the Harrison Order such that the well ordered initial segment is exactly the set of things less than this element.

Comment: @William So is my general statement about $A$, $B$, and $X$ not true?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It is not true. Another example: by an easy finite injury argument, we can come up with a computable total order of ordertype $\omega+\omega^*$, such that neither the $\omega$ nor $\omega^*$ part is a computable subset.